# How to get the first object of an array by condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, postman

I have a response:
Response body:

```js
[
    {
        "id": "6094f8253e2bf70001827add",
        "name": "groupdk2502",
        "type": "One",
        
    },
    {
        "id": "5f7ae257c64bb7000168175a",
        "name": "Badminton Vejle",
        "type": "Group",
        
    },
    {
        "id": "5f76c43cec5fdeb57baa0c31",
        "name": "Nl-golf Vejle",
        "type": "Group",
        
    },
    {
        "id": "5f7ae258c64bb7000168176f",
        "name": "Schaatsen Vejle",
        "type": "Group",
        
    },
    {
        "id": "5f7ae258c64bb70001681775",
        "name": "Bridge Vejle",
        "type": "Group",
        
    }
]
```

I receive an array with 5 objects. I want to set the variable for the first object within "type": "Group". [attachment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea0Nz.png).
But I don't know the way. Does anyone help me???

Comment: Why not use `.fitler`?

Comment: what do you mean by `set the variable for the first object within "type": "Group".`

Comment: @evolutionxbox `.filter` would require iterating through the entire array, when that is not necessary

Comment: @Hive7 sure, but so does `.find`? (until a match is found at least)

Comment: Find will exit once it finds the first occurrence, `.filter` will not. Filter will also create a new  list @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `.find` which returns the first occurrence matching a predicate or undefined. For example:

```js
data.find(x => x.type === "Group");
```

See the example below

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": "6094f8253e2bf70001827add",
        "name": "groupdk2502",
        "type": "One",
        
    },
    {
        "id": "5f7ae257c64bb7000168175a",
        "name": "Badminton Vejle",
        "type": "Group",
        
    },
    {
        "id": "5f76c43cec5fdeb57baa0c31",
        "name": "Nl-golf Vejle",
        "type": "Group",
        
    },
    {
        "id": "5f7ae258c64bb7000168176f",
        "name": "Schaatsen Vejle",
        "type": "Group",
        
    },
    {
        "id": "5f7ae258c64bb70001681775",
        "name": "Bridge Vejle",
        "type": "Group",
        
    }
];

const first = data.find(x => x.type === "Group");
console.log(first);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly find the first element by [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: "6094f8253e2bf70001827add",
    name: "groupdk2502",
    type: "One",
  },
  {
    id: "5f7ae257c64bb7000168175a",
    name: "Badminton Vejle",
    type: "Group",
  },
  {
    id: "5f76c43cec5fdeb57baa0c31",
    name: "Nl-golf Vejle",
    type: "Group",
  },
  {
    id: "5f7ae258c64bb7000168176f",
    name: "Schaatsen Vejle",
    type: "Group",
  },
  {
    id: "5f7ae258c64bb70001681775",
    name: "Bridge Vejle",
    type: "Group",
  },
];

const first = arr.find((o) => o.type === "Group");
console.log(first);
```

Also using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then find the `result[0]`

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: "6094f8253e2bf70001827add",
    name: "groupdk2502",
    type: "One",
  },
  {
    id: "5f7ae257c64bb7000168175a",
    name: "Badminton Vejle",
    type: "Group",
  },
  {
    id: "5f76c43cec5fdeb57baa0c31",
    name: "Nl-golf Vejle",
    type: "Group",
  },
  {
    id: "5f7ae258c64bb7000168176f",
    name: "Schaatsen Vejle",
    type: "Group",
  },
  {
    id: "5f7ae258c64bb70001681775",
    name: "Bridge Vejle",
    type: "Group",
  },
];

const result = arr.filter((o) => o.type === "Group");
const first = result[0];
console.log(first);
```

Comment: Isn't this just a much less efficient version of  `.find`?

Comment: @Hive7 Both answer updated. It just came first in my mind.

Comment: @Hive7 It is just another way, but that was not wrong at all.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let res = [
    {
        "id": "6094f8253e2bf70001827add",
        "name": "groupdk2502",
        "type": "One",
        
    },
    {
        "id": "5f7ae257c64bb7000168175a",
        "name": "Badminton Vejle",
        "type": "Group",
        
    },
    {
        "id": "5f76c43cec5fdeb57baa0c31",
        "name": "Nl-golf Vejle",
        "type": "Group",
        
    },
    {
        "id": "5f7ae258c64bb7000168176f",
        "name": "Schaatsen Vejle",
        "type": "Group",
        
    },
    {
        "id": "5f7ae258c64bb70001681775",
        "name": "Bridge Vejle",
        "type": "Group",
        
    }
]

let ans = res.find((f) => f.type === "Group")
console.log(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```js
    let res = [
      {
          "id": "6094f8253e2bf70001827add",
          "name": "groupdk2502",
          "type": "One",
          
      },
      {
          "id": "5f7ae257c64bb7000168175a",
          "name": "Badminton Vejle",
          "type": "Group",
          
      },
      {
          "id": "5f76c43cec5fdeb57baa0c31",
          "name": "Nl-golf Vejle",
          "type": "Group",
          
      },
      {
          "id": "5f7ae258c64bb7000168176f",
          "name": "Schaatsen Vejle",
          "type": "Group",
          
      },
      {
          "id": "5f7ae258c6t56d700168174p",
          "name": "Some Name",
          "type": "One",
          
      },
      {
          "id": "5f7ae258c64bb70001681775",
          "name": "Bridge Vejle",
          "type": "Group",
          
      }
    ];
    
    let getFirstGroup = arr => {
      // loop over every object in the array
      for(let obj of arr){
        // if the type of current object (obj) is "Group", then return that object
        if(obj.type == "Group")
          return obj;
      }
      
      // else, return false
      return false;
    };
    
    let first = getFirstGroup(res);
    console.log(first); // prints out second object in the array
```